# Не работает IPointerEnterHandler и IPointerExitHandler

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь сделать Grid Inventory System в Unity, для этого требуется работа с EventSystems. Но по какой-то неизвестной мне причине не работает, скачивал даже отдельные проекты все равно не работает. Буду очень благодарен за предоставленную помощь
Вот код:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ItemGrid))]
public class GridInteract : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    InventoryController inventoryController;
    ItemGrid itemGrid;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inventoryController = FindObjectOfType(typeof(InventoryController)) as InventoryController;
        itemGrid = GetComponent<ItemGrid>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Enter");
        inventoryController.selectedItemGrid = itemGrid;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Exit");
        inventoryController.selectedItemGrid = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы-ответы, которые выдаёт поиск, уже читали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=OnPointerEnter

Comment: Да читал, не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт нашел решение проблемы, нужно было добавить 2d коллайдер на объект

Comment: А, ну да, это же основа. Без коллайдера нет столкновений.